# Vanilla JS not(this)

Tags: javascript

I am looking for an easy and clean Vanilla JS solution for this jQuery code:

```
   $(this).addClass('highlighted');
   $('button').not(this).removeClass('highlighted');
```

When I click a specific button element, it should add the class `'highlighted'`, all the other button elements `not(this)` should have the `highlighted` class removed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your buttons have IDs, using them would be a good solution. Otherwise, you can simply filter the results from `querySelectorAll`:

Using ids:

```js
function highlight(event) {
  const target = event.target;
  target.classList.add('highlighted');
  document.querySelectorAll(`button:not(#${target.id})`).forEach(item => item.classList.remove('highlighted'));
}
```

```css
.highlighted {
  background: pink
}
```

```html
<button id="btn1" onclick="highlight(event)">Button 1</button>
<button id="btn2" onclick="highlight(event)">Button 2</button>
<button id="btn3" onclick="highlight(event)">Button 3</button>
<button id="btn4" onclick="highlight(event)">Button 4</button>
```

Filtering the results:

```js
function highlight(event) {
  const target = event.target;
  target.classList.add('highlighted');
  Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(`button`)).filter(item => item != target).forEach(item => item.classList.remove('highlighted'));
}
```

```css
.highlighted {
  background: pink
}
```

```html
<button onclick="highlight(event)">Button 1</button>
<button onclick="highlight(event)">Button 2</button>
<button onclick="highlight(event)">Button 3</button>
<button onclick="highlight(event)">Button 4</button>
```

Comment: Yet another solution for this very specific use case is to remove the class 'highlighted' from all the buttons BEFORE adding it to the target element. I didn't include it in my answer because it doesn't use the knowledge proposed by the question (translating jQuery's `not(this)` to vanilla JS).

Answer (score 1):

If you remove the highlighted class from all buttons first, you can add it afterward to the only highlighted button.

```js
const stripHighlighted = (button) => {
  button.classList.remove("highlighted");
}
document.querySelectorAll("button").forEach(stripHighlighted);
this.classList.add("highlighted");
```